# Ubuntu 20.04 libGL error Messages when Start Anaconda3

Tags: drivers, nvidia, anaconda

After Install Anaconda in Ubuntu 20.04 and launch it using `anaconda-navigator`this error Messages appear

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus: /usr/lib/dri/crocus_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libGL error: failed to load driver: crocus

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open crocus: /usr/lib/dri/crocus_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libGL error: failed to load driver: crocus

libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

My laptop have 2 Video Card Intel and Nvidia Geforce 810 drive version 510.
Ubuntu 20.4
Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64
Thank you